# How to hide client side api keys?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, frontend, client-side, api-key

so I want users in my app to say places they've been and I want to use google maps API and make a request here:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London&key=MY_API_KEY`

so that I can get the long latitude and plot on a map

the problem is if I make a request to that url above I fear I might expose my API key so someone looking in the network tab would just be able to steal it when it makes the request

I know I can hide them in my source code with environment variables. but is there a way to hide/jumble them from the network tab? or am I going to have to completely rethink my approach?

Comment: I would suggest having a proxy of some sort on the backend to handle the request.

Answer (score 2):

You should use it request on the backend

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is if I make a request to that url above I fear I might
>   expose my API key so someone looking in the network tab would just be
>   able to steal it when it makes the request

Your can [restrict your API key in Google Cloud Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key#restrict_key)

[image: google cloud platform manage credentials]

@Владислав also recommended calling API on the server. Another reason for that would be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)